# Checkout Delivery Method Input Field

Tags: checkout, frontend

I'd like to add a custom input field to checkout when a customer selects a flat shipping rate, which is compulsory.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Please check the following third party custom fields extension for Magento, you can add, remove custom fields on checkout page. You can also set the position of fields, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/additional-checkout-attributes-custom-fields-manager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up referencing this module:

> http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-shipping-method-development?facebook=1

Which does pretty much exactly what I was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Moose , Please check the below links and hope it is helping u

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943923/display-date-picker-in-magento-checkout-page
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252516/how-to-add-extra-amount-field-in-magento-checkout-process

Comment: Thanks Amit, got me pointed in the right direction. Link to the module I ended up using posted as an answer